# how to create a loop over a different set of variables and models in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation

code below first prints out `lm` for `mpg ~ disp` then for `mpg ~ disp + wt`. I would like to create another loop over the models (note that the second lm is my personalize model, and for the simplicity, we can assume it is `lm`). how can I loop over different models?

```
data("mtcars")

formulas <- list(
  mpg ~ disp,
  mpg ~ disp + wt
)

    models <- list(lm, lm)
    
    res <- vector("list", length = length(formulas))
    
    for(i in seq_along(formulas)){
      res[[i]] <- lm(formulas[[i]], data = mtcars)
    
    }
    res
    
    or
    
    lapply(formulas, lm, data = mtcars)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231681/r-for-loop-for-regression-lmyx/32236702 might be useful :)

Comment: hello, thank you but it seems to be they only loop over the formulas not the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use nested `lapply` -

```
lapply(models, function(x) lapply(formulas, function(y) x(y, data = mtcars)))
```

Comment: `mpg ~ disp` and ``mpg ~ disp + wt` should be printed twice  as the length of moduls.

Comment: See the updated answer. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I like to use tidyverse's `purrr` for such multi-model approaches:

```
pacman::p_load(dplyr, purrr)
data("mtcars")

d <- crossing(formula = c(mpg ~ disp, mpg ~ disp + wt),
              model = list("lm", "glm")) %>% 
  
  mutate(result = pmap(.l = list(model, formula),
                       .f = function(m, f) do.call(m, args = list(formula = f, data = substitute(mtcars)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `outer` in `base R` and should be fast

```
out <- c(outer(models, formulas, Vectorize(function(x, y) list(x(y, data = mtcars)))))
```